# Python, SetBackgroundColour on TextCtrl does not work

Tags: python, wxpython

http://pastebin.com/z9r43y0L

Try that example, then press the "Save" button.

A red frame around the TextCtrl will still be there. I do not want this red frame. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: the red went away when i hit save...

Comment: the red does ... what version of wx do you have?

Comment: the newest version of 2.9, and im using xp

Comment: I can still see a red frame like thing around the control, but when I hover over it, it goes away

Comment: i think im using 2.8 ... and on win7 so who knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce something similar with wxPython 2.9.3 on Windows 7.  I didn't get a red 'frame' around the TextCtrl, but I did get a red pixel at each corner.  These red pixels went away when I hovered over the TextCtrl.

I found that replacing the line

```
    self.editname.Refresh()
```

in the `OnClick` function with

```
    self.editname.Parent.Refresh()
```

got rid of the red pixels at the corners without the need for a hover-over.